# Help building up LINQ query when using anonymous types

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've started out with:

```
IQueryable<Author> authors2 = db.Authors;
```

Then I build up `authors2` in multiple if statements, here's one of them

```
authors2 = authors2.Where(t => t.ItemAuthors.Any(b => b.Item.CategoryItems.Any(z => z.categoryID == int.Parse(ddlCategory.SelectedValue))));
```

Then finally I would like to append this to the end of the built up where clauses

```
authors2.OrderBy(x => x.text).Select(x => new
            {
                authorText = string.Format("{0} ({1})",x.text, x.ItemAuthors.Count())
            });
```

To bind a control like this:

```
ddlAuthor.DataSource = authors2;
            ddlAuthor.DataTextField = "authorText";
            ddlAuthor.DataBind();
```

Apparently the compiler is not very happy about my select new statement. How can I rewrite this to achieve the same goal? I believe this is called creating an anonymous type.

It says *an explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)* I can't figure out how to cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third statement, the returned type is not same as authors2 because the Select projects a different type other than Author

So assign the value to a new variable

```
var authorsFinal = authors2
                    .OrderBy(x => x.text)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                      authorText = string.Format("{0} ({1})",
                                                 x.text, 
                                                 x.ItemAuthors.Count())
                    });
```